# Qlikview Scatter Plot

Tags: scatter-plot, qlikview

I'm trying to plot distinct values by date in Qlikview.  How do I recreate the Excel scatter plot in Qlik?  If there are multiple values per day I get an average value.  I want to display all values on a given date.[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2jim.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the FILE column as the dimension and then max(DATE) and avg(DATA) as expressions.

The max() and avg() will actually do nothing since the FILE dimension keeps the values unique, just Qlik might get grumpy about expressions that don't have an aggregation function